# Installation of Windows XP on Dell Inspiron fails due to BSOD

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I have a Dell Inspiron with an i3 processor and I need to install Windows XP. When I try to  install it, I get this blue screen:

[image]

Why is that? What can I do to install Windows?

#### EDIT

in the bios, if I try change to `ATA`, I get other BSOD with a `process1_initialization_failed` message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has no relation to your processor. It means that you have no SATA drivers. You need a working floppy dive to install XP on a new motherboard.

Comment: Not necessarily: [Install Windows XP on SATA without a Floppy (F6)](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Install-Windows-XP-On-SATA-Without-a-Floppy-F6-47807.shtml)

Comment: One can also install Windows in IDE mone and install AHCI drivers later, but it’s harder.

Answer (score 3):

The error's got nothing to do with your processor. WIndows XP supports your i3 fine, your hard drive cannot be seen because it's a SATA drive running in AHCI mode with no drivers for Windows to detect it.

Either load the AHCI drivers or change the SATA mode to IDE mode from AHCI which will reduce the performance.

Comment: in the bios, I try change to ATA, but now I get other blue screen with `PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED`

Answer (score -2):

I think you just got problem with your Installer Disc, Your installer mayber the old version of windows xp which didnt support SATA Controller and just compatible with IDE driver, try to change the installer disc with new one which compatible with SATA disk, ia think your HDD is SATA, not IDE.

Comment: No XP version comes with AHCI support. [It *is* possible to build your own XP CD that does (slipstreaming).](http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/TSB85017Z0000R01.htm)